# Confidence interval for all rows of a dataframe - t distribution

Tags: r, dataframe, confidence-interval

I'm trying to calculate confidence intervals for all rows in a dataframe

I've been using something like this for a normal distribution:

```
function(x){
  mean(x)+c(-1.96,1.96)*sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
}
```

Any advice how to modify the above for a t-distribution? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to focus on statistical analysis rather than programming as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

try the below. I broke it down in parts but also provided the function similar to yours.

```
## In parts
n <- 25
x <- sample(1:100, n, replace = TRUE)
mean <- mean(x)
sd <- sd(x)
error <- qt(0.975, df = n-1) * sd / sqrt(n)
lower <- mean - error
upper <- mean + error

# As function
example_function <- function(x){
  tCI <- mean(x)+c(-( qt(0.975, df = n-1) * sd / sqrt(n)),  qt(0.975, df = n-1) * sd / sqrt(n))
  tCI
}
example_function(x)


# > lower
# [1] 37.23457
# > upper
# [1] 60.76543
# > example_function(x)
# [1] 37.23457 60.76543
```

Comment: No problem! If no better solutions come about, consider accepting this as the solution or upvoting if others have a similar question